# DateTime::createFromFormat with timezone does change output

Tags: php, datetime

Regardless, of what timezone I feed in, I get same result.

I expected time fed into (2nd argument) to be UTC - it does not seem to be.

In such case, what is the use of third argument - timezone, if we do not get time in selected timezone, but repetition of time we fed into?

I see offset (in parentheses), but fail to understand, how is that practically useful.

I appreciate, if someone would explain, what I do not get here right.

When I use:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-05-31 10:00:56", new DateTimeZone('America/Fortaleza'));
```

I get this:

```
DateTime @1559307656 {#1978
  date: 2019-05-31 10:00:56.0 America/Fortaleza (-03:00),
}
```

I expected to get:

```
DateTime @1559307656 {#1978
  date: 2019-05-31 07:00:56.0 America/Fortaleza (-03:00),
}
```

Actually, I do not get any change, regardless of timezone fed in:

```
>>> DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-05-31 10:00:56", new DateTimeZone('UTC'))
DateTime @1559296856 {#1979
  date: 2019-05-31 10:00:56.0 UTC (+00:00),
}

>>> DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-05-31 10:00:56", new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'))
DateTime @1559286056 {#1958
  date: 2019-05-31 10:00:56.0 Europe/Moscow (+03:00),
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect to see any of those values? Which actual timezone is that original value from?

Comment: Lets say: Europe/Warsaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the use of the third parameter. It is used to tell [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) what the timezone of the time you have passed in is, which also becomes the timezone of the result. If your input time is `UTC`, that is the appropriate value for the third parameter, and you can then use [`DateTime::setTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to set the timezone of the value:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-05-31 10:00:56", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Fortaleza'));
var_dump($date);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=> string(26) "2019-05-31 07:00:56.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
  ["timezone"]=> string(17) "America/Fortaleza" 
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/k0bOe)

Comment: I see it was the other way around. First timezone tells php what we feed, second one, what we expect. Thank you Nick.